# How to add support for websocket nest.js to an http server?

Tags: node.js, express

I created a server in nest.js, however I listen to the server not `app.listen`, but `http.createServer(server).listen(port)`. Since in the future I will need to create an https server, which the standard app.listen does not allow. How can I `http.createServer(server).listen(port)` add websocket support here?
Here is my code

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as https from 'https';
import * as http from 'http';

const server = express();
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(MainAppModule, new ExpressAdapter(server));
http.createServer(server).listen(config.port); //this prevents the use of sockets
//app.listen(port) this allows the use of sockets
```

Comment: Did you look at the `ws` library?